# Different chats for different pages of a website (Socket.io and Node.js)

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I’m not really good in programming yet, so I’ve some problems with things that could appear really easy for someone else. In particular I’m now creating a website that I want it to have two different chats in the 2 different pages it owns. I have to use Socket.io. I’ve already built it but when I type something on one page, the message appears even in the other page even if I want the two chats to be separated. Are Rooms useful as I found on internet to ‘separate’ the two chats? Could someone help me and teach me ho to use them if they are really useful in this case or just help me to solve my problem? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what is going on without seeing any code. But sounds like both chats are connecting to the same server (socket). You could simply separate the events so the chats are not listening to the same thing.

So something like this:

```
socket.emit('chat1', data1);

socket.emit('chat2, data2);
```

Then you code each chat to listen to the events that pertain to them. And the same goes for events your server is listening too (coming from the client):

```
socket.on('message from chat 1', message => {})

socket.on('message from chat 2', message => {})
```

Again not sure if this would be the right thing for your particular case without seeing any code.

Comment: Thank you. Here you can find all my code: https://github.com/emanueleelias-ita/chatroom . The website works for the page index.html and Milano.html, but I want their two chats to be separated